# AMCL Global Localization Upside Down

Tags: navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems like AMCL does a really bad job of localizing in the map.  I'm using the global_localization service to distribute the particles across the map initially, but the results are things like this:
[image: image description]

when in fact the robot is staring at a corner like this:
[image: image description]

Thoughts on what I'm missing here?  Or what I need to look into to improve my results?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242074/amcl-global-localization-upside-down/) by [ElizabethA](https://answers.ros.org/users/26773/elizabetha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2016-08-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are just interested in the localization and it doesn't matter if it is global localization, then you can give it starting pose through the "2D Pose Estimate" button in Rviz. Then it will try to localize with respect to this initial point.

The issue with AMCL is that with the global localization you cannot be sure it converges to the correct localization due to aliasing and the probabilistic nature of the particle filter.

---

Originally posted by [FOXTER](https://answers.ros.org/users/26976/foxter/) with karma: 153 on 2016-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0